# How to get content of a website which calls a JSON file using PHP/cURL

Tags: php, ajax, json, curl

There is a supermarket website and I need to get list of product name and price data.
The website is: http://www.sanalmarket.com.tr/kweb/sclist/30011-tum-meyveler

However, I cannot get this content with success. Every attempt finalized with a null result. I am not familiar with cURL, but it is recommended me to overcome this issue. As I see, the product list is called with Ajax - JSON and for this reason, I should follow requests to see JSON files and their contents using PHP. ...But how?

Thank you in advance.

The code I tried:

```
<?php
$url="https://www.sanalmarket.com.tr/kweb/sclist/30011-tum-meyveler";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));

?>
```

Comment: @mithunsatheesh
It is added.

Comment: Why not call the json request direct? If it is dynamic, you need to download the website to string (`file_get_contents`) and extract the url maybe with `DomDocument` or `Regex`. Try it and if you have a specific problem you can ask. For me, this is in the current state way to broad.

Comment: I looked into the structure of the page and the Ajax/JSON request to load products, and from what I can tell, I don't think you'll be able to easily get the information you want. First, the URL you are using in CURL is for the webpage itself, not for the URL that returns the product info. Second, the product info URL only returns a value if you send a valid cookie, so you would need a way to get a cookie from the original URL, store it, and then use it for scraping the AJAX URL. I hope that helps.

Comment: @hargobind At least I've a roadmap thanks to you. To get cookie list from URL helps me, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your curl request did work and you are getting html response in the `$result` variable. The problem is that you are treating the html response string like a valid JSON string.

instead of

```
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

try

```
var_dump($result);
```

Here `$result` is not a valid JSON string. It is a string containing the html that the server responded. So you cannot parse it directly into an array or object without using a html parser.

Comment: Not my vote. I haven't got enough rep to vote someone. You're right. Now I can see something, but still it is not the thing I want. My fault.

Comment: @DorukhanArslan : response is html and you are passing it to json decode. So json decode expects valid json string and you dint provide one.

Comment: Actually, I have no idea how can I find that specific JSON string from source code and pass it.